# R error - Non-numeric Argument to Binary Operator

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a new column "age_years", by running this command:

```
linelist <- linelist %>% 
  mutate(age_years = case_when(
    age_unit == "years"  ~ age,       # if age is given in years
    age_unit == "months" ~ age/12,    # if age is given in months
    is.na(age_unit)      ~ age,       # if age unit is missing, assume years
    TRUE                 ~ NA_real_)) # any other circumstance, assign missing
```

However when I do that, I get this error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `age_years`. 
i `age_years = case_when(...)`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

When I run `rlang::last_error()` to learn more I get this:

```
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Problem with `mutate()` column `age_years`.
i `age_years = case_when(...)`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
Backtrace:
  1. `%>%`(...)
  9. base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 10. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
```

When I run `rlang::last_trace()` I get this:

```
<error/dplyr:::mutate_error>
Problem with `mutate()` column `age_years`.
i `age_years = case_when(...)`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
Backtrace:
     x
  1. +-`%>%`(...)
  2. +-dplyr::mutate(...)
  3. +-dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
  4. | \-dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, ..., caller_env = caller_env())
  5. |   +-base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  6. |   \-mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
  7. +-dplyr::case_when(...)
  8. | \-rlang::eval_tidy(pair$rhs, env = default_env)
  9. \-base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 10.   \-dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
<error/simpleError>
non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you add output of `dput(linelist)` to let us discuss about your data ?

Comment: Your column `age` should be a non numeric column. By the way we cannot reproduce your error, for that you have to provide a data sample.

Comment: Can you supply output of `class(linelist); class(linelist$age); class(linelist$age_unit)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your code. Now it works flawlessly.

```
library(tidyverse)

n = 100
linelist = tibble(
  age = sample(10:40, n, replace = TRUE),
  age_unit = sample(c("years", "months", NA, "other"), n, replace = TRUE)
)

linelist <- linelist %>% 
  mutate(age_years = case_when(
    age_unit == "years"  ~ as.double(age),       # if age is given in years
    age_unit == "months" ~ as.double(age)/12,    # if age is given in months
    is.na(age_unit)      ~ as.double(age),       # if age unit is missing, assume years
    TRUE                 ~ NA_real_))
    
linelist
```

output

```
# A tibble: 100 x 3
     age age_unit age_years
   <int> <chr>        <dbl>
 1    19 NA          19    
 2    11 months       0.917
 3    29 NA          29    
 4    32 months       2.67 
 5    29 NA          29    
 6    20 months       1.67 
 7    25 months       2.08 
 8    13 years       13    
 9    10 years       10    
10    24 NA          24    
# ... with 90 more rows
```

This works even if the `age` is of type `chr`

```
linelist = tibble(
  age = sample(paste(10:40), n, replace = TRUE),
  age_unit = sample(c("years", "months", NA, "other"), n, replace = TRUE)
)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 100 x 2
   age   age_unit
   <chr> <chr>   
 1 27    years   
 2 26    months  
 3 23    years   
 4 30    years   
 5 37    months  
 6 17    NA      
 7 16    months  
 8 33    other   
 9 36    other   
10 12    months
```

And next

```
linelist <- linelist %>% 
  mutate(age_years = case_when(
    age_unit == "years"  ~ as.double(age),       # if age is given in years
    age_unit == "months" ~ as.double(age)/12,    # if age is given in months
    is.na(age_unit)      ~ as.double(age),       # if age unit is missing, assume years
    TRUE                 ~ NA_real_))

linelist
```

output

```
# A tibble: 100 x 3
   age   age_unit age_years
   <chr> <chr>        <dbl>
 1 27    years        27   
 2 26    months        2.17
 3 23    years        23   
 4 30    years        30   
 5 37    months        3.08
 6 17    NA           17   
 7 16    months        1.33
 8 33    other        NA   
 9 36    other        NA   
10 12    months        1   
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: Adding `as.double` to my code fixed it, thanks!

Comment: Yes you are right. Read the documentation for the `case_when` function [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/case_when). The key here is the information "all RHSs must evaluate to the same type of vector."